# Sampling on count of specific column value in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sampling

I have a table with a set of values, table example is

```
ID  |  Customer_name  | workorder
1   |    abc          | dispatch
2   |    xyz          | not_dispatch
3   |    jdk          | dispatch
```

and this goes on for a total of 1M rows.. now I want to sample this dataset to 5000 rows and I want 3400 workorders as 'not_dispatch' and 1600 with 'dispatch' in the sample. 
How can this be done in PostgreSQL .

Comment: So do you want a 5000 record sample with 3400 not dispatch and 1600 with dispatch?

Comment: yes , from the 1M rows I just wantto sample 5000 records .. with 3400 having not_dispatch and 1600 having dispatch

Comment: Do you want to sample in any particular way?  Taking a random sample from so many records (1 million) might not be so efficient.

Comment: I am not sure if this will answer your question but sampling on a particular customer name, but I am not sure if systematic random sampling or plain random sampling would be better. I want the correct representation of both dispatch and non dispatch, I did not take different customers into consideration , but that also would be nice.

Comment: I select 3400 and 1600 as I used a calculated approach to find the count of total dispatches and not_dispatches to find the ratio and then figured for a 5000 rows 3400 and 1600 is the more appropriate one. But this is a very naive approach.. if you can help me with a better approach I would be very happy.

Comment: Which version of PG are you using?

Comment: @Patrick i am using PostgreSQL 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far from efficient, but effective:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  WHERE workorder = 'dispatch' -- other filters
  ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1600) sub1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  WHERE workorder = 'not_dispatch' -- other filters
  ORDER BY random() LIMIT 3400) sub2;
```